Forming real symmetric positive semidefinite matrices from complex matrices.
Let $Q \in \mathbb{C}^{n\times n}$ be any matrix. When can we say that the matrix $A=Q^{t}Q$ (where $Q^{t}$ denotes the transpose of a matrix) is a real symmetric positive semidefinite matrix?
Write $Q=[q_{1}\ q_{2}\cdots q_{n}],$ where $q_{j}$'s are columns of the marix $Q$. An immediate observation is that $A=Q^{t}Q$ has to be a real matrix so that $q_{j}^{t}q_{i}$ is real for all $1\leq i,j\leq n$. I am looking for some conditions to be imposed on $Q$ so that $A$ is a real PSD.

Are you looking for a condition other than "$Q$ is real"?

I think the condition is that when $Q^tQ$ has all real non-negative eigenvalues

It has to be Hermitian so $A$ must equal its conjugate transpose. If you don't take the conjugate this forces $A$ to be a real symmetric matrix. So it's the same conditions as in the real case.

The usual thing is just to $  \bar{Q}^T Q =A   $

@QiaochuYuan Yes, I'm looking for the conditions when Q is not necessarily a real matrix.

@CyclotomicField I want A to be real symmetric positive semidefinite and Q is not necessarily a real matrix.

@Mthpd then it can't be the transpose, it has to be the conjugate transpose. The only matrices where the conjugate transpose and transpose are the same are when they matrices are real.

@CyclotomicField My question is to characterize all complex matrices Q such that $Q^{t}Q$ is a symmetric positive semidefinite matrix when considered as a real matrix.

@Mthpd and what I'm telling you is that as complex matrices that can only happen when they're real matrices. It's forced by the hermitian requirement.

@CyclotomicField If we take $Q = \begin{pmatrix}  0\ i \ 0\ 2 \end{pmatrix}$ then $Q^{t}Q$ is a real PSD but $Q$ is not a real matrix.
